# Why does python put 'A' in global namespace when I import A.B.C

Tags: python, python-import

I am reading about how `import` works in python.

When I do:

```
import A.B.C
```

1. A, A.B, A.B.C are put in `sys.modules`. Expected.
2. A's `__init__`, A.B's `__init__` get executed. Expected.

But here is a surprise: When I print `globals()`, only `A` is put into the namespace, while 'A.B.C' is not. I expect 'A.B.C' to be in global namespace.

And this means, I can access A.x defined in A's `__init__`.

Why is `import` implemented this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `objects`/`names` are put in globals namespace. `A.B.C` is not a valid name.

In your above case, the object is the module object for `A` , and its name is `A` .

In this particular case, if you do -

```
dir(A)
```

You would see `B` inside it, and that means its an attribute of the module object `A` . If you do -

```
hasattr(A,'B')
```

It would return True.

And in the same way if you do - `dir(A.B)` , you would be able to see `C` in it , and `C` is an attribute of `A.B` .

---

A Very simple example to show this -

My directory structur -

```
shared/
      __init__.py
      pkg/
         __init__.py
         b.py
```

Then in code I do -

```
>>> import shared.pkg.b
>>> dir(shared)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'pkg']
>>> hasattr(shared,'pkg')
True
>>>
>>> dir(shared.pkg)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'b']
>>> hasattr(shared.pkg,'b')
True
```

Answer (score 3):

B and C are reachable through A.

eg.

```
import A.B.C
print(A.B.C)
```

If you want B and C to appear directly in your current namespace then do

```
from A import B
from A.B import C

print(B, C)
```